# Getting MS-Outlook embedded images and saving them within the file system using MS-Access VBA

Tags: image, vba, outlook

I have a very special question concerning MS-Outlook and MS-Access VBA. I want to import the email data from outlook into a database (and the file system > attachments and embedded images). Using Google I find ways to get the emails incl. emails properties and the attachments. But I need images too which are embedded in rich text- and html-emails. Is there a way to realize this via VBA?

Thanks in advance.

Tommy

Answer (score 0):

Embedded HTML images are just regular image attachments and can be saved using `Attachment.SaveAsFile`.

Embedded RTF images are a different story: they are OLE objects, and `Attachment.SaveAsFile` will fail. You can use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) for that - its [RDOAttachment](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/history.htm).`SaveAsFile` will extract WMF, Word, Excel, PowerPoint, PDF, etc. attachments from the attachment OLE storage and save them as files.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I found another way > exporting outlook emails as rtf documents (including the OLE objects). That's great and OK!

Comment: @TommySaber - Hi - please let us know which solution you have found. Im facing the same problem...